# Ubuntu 12.04/xp dual boot testdisk wrote the wrong mbr to my storage disk

Tags: ntfs, mbr, format, ext4, testdisk

Using disk Utility in Ubuntu 12.04, I inadvertently formatted my 1TB ext4 storage disk to NTFS. I was in the process of doing clean installs so I just pulled the drive and set up a usb hdd dock to copy files to another hdd.  After copying the files I swapped in the 1TB drive to get to work with testdisk and image the ntfs formatted ext4 drive. everything was peachy, I could see all my files and got the image process going.  Something went wrong and I had to back out of the image process. when I shut down testdisk it wrote its mbr, but it wrote the one for the drive I had been copying files off of earlier.  So I have a 1tb ext4 disk that thinks it is a 400gb ntfs disk and testdisk just spits out "bad superblock" errors and says partitions cannot be recovered.  I think that if I can erase the testdisk mbr I can get at the data underneath. But....this is years of data I collected so I don't want to make anymore mistakes.  Thoughts? help? please?